# Fancybox doesn't work, image opens in same window

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I am trying to the fancybox working but I can get it to work. I have been searching the forum, but I can't the answers that helps me undrstand what I am doing wrong. Maybe not necessary to say, but I am a real starter with jQuery.

I have a code like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> <!-- Resource style -->
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" /> <!-- fancybox -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script> <!-- fancybox -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

When I have a short code it works fine.I have hosted the site at [this site](http://psteintj.home.xs4all.nl/). Could someone tell me what I have done wrond and how I fix it.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I didn't mention that firebug says: TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function
 

$(".fancybox").fancybox();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
There is a jquery conflict, because of two jquery versions. 
Add all your js file to the bottom and in the following order just before </body>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script> <!-- fancybox -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script> <!-- Resource jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
        });
    </script>


Please remove all javascripts from the head section.

so your head section looks like :-

<head>
    <title>Alternate Fixed And Scroll Backgrounds</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://psteintj.home.xs4all.nl/css/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://psteintj.home.xs4all.nl/css/style.css"> <!-- Resource style -->


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://psteintj.home.xs4all.nl/css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" /> <!-- fancybox -->

</head>
```

Comment: Many thanx, this has solved the problem. But how can I prevent that this will happen again. In other words how can I prevent ( how do I know ) that there is a jQuery conflict. Why have all the js files be placed on the bottom, does that improve the working of the file, or don't the work when the are placed in the top? I saw a tutorial on Youtube and there where these files placed in the top.

Comment: always use one version of jquery. You had used two different versions.
It is recommended to have all the javascripts at the bottom of the page and all css in the head section. So that javascript do not obstruct the presentation of the page. As they normally are required when the dom is ready or loaded

Comment: Again many thanx. After the problem has been solved I have been trying to understand how to use jQuery and avoid problems like I have had, and I still have a couple of questions. When I am right ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js is main jQuery version and that one was in conflict with: code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js. Is it possible to replace the one with the other? And when I am looking at the jQuery page I see a version V.1.11 and V2.1. Is it right when I say that the version use: ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js is version V.1.11.

Comment: And what determines which version to use. When I want to make use of an other element with js I only have to add the specific js elements like js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5 in case of fancybox the main js file is stored in ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js is version V.1.11.. What determines the order of js File at the bottom, why places them in this order. At last if there are any books or videos that could help me understanding jQuery I would glad to be informed of. There is a lot on youtube but none who helped me to solve this problem.

Comment: Jquery's own website is a really great place to learn. The order is important because fancybox requires jquery.